# Call for Youtube Video Returns no Data

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

We are trying to get analytics data from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYJuxMfXGz0

With this API call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?dimensions=video,day&end-date=2018-02-26&filters=video==HuCHxi-KEeY,5pnUq2Onvgk,AYJuxMfXGz0,rXG0sg2yJQA,AysuRD2onnU,4mFtBgNAClI,JBdCK4QeTiQ,yzEIqFmfSTw,1CGAUUj6VFY,3GmE6xJu934,0Rz2jIdwJbo,hD20mX-D98s,Zk2oo_-G5pg,8yQ6ldrkrDk,twW_GFOD0SI,DAD5SsgsKW4,etNZnm1KGNQ,5rxePj4cMKs,C-SKH_b3Rk4,_ZbgCgoAU_E&ids=channel==UCInsB_XtGXHq7_TmhNVFk0g&metrics=views,comments,likes,dislikes,shares,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,annotationClickThroughRate,annotationCloseRate,subscribersGained,subscribersLost&start-date=2018-02-26

However, the response being returned is empty:

{

}

Any insights would be helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: If you haven't done so, try to pattern your API request in the format provided in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests).

Comment: This does not resolve the issue, no.

Comment: This continues to be an issue.

Comment: This still continues to be an issue.